# flask-sqlalchemy: how to Insert duplicated record in many-to-many relationship for multiple times

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy and trying to insert duplicated record in many-to-many relationship. However, only one item can be inserted. For example, consider the following code:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
call_global_variable = db.Table('call_global_variable',
    db.Column('call_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('call.id')),
    db.Column('global_variable_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('global_variable.id'))
)
class Call(db.Model):
    __tablename__           = 'call'
    id                      = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)

    callee_id               = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('function.id'))
    callee                  = db.relationship('Function', foreign_keys = [callee_id])
    arg_list                = db.relationship('GlobalVariable', secondary = call_global_variable, lazy = 'dynamic')

class Function(db.Model):
    __tablename__           = 'function'
    id                      = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name                    = db.Column(db.String(20))
    type                    = db.Column(db.String(20))
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class GlobalVariable(db.Model):
    __tablename__           = 'global_variable'
    id                      = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name                    = db.Column(db.String(20))
    type                    = db.Column(db.String(20))
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

func = Function(name = 'func', type = 'void')
gvar0 = GlobalVariable(name = 'a', type = 'int')
gvar1 = GlobalVariable(name = 'b', type = 'int')
call = Call(callee = func, arg_list = [gvar0, gvar0, gvar0, gvar0, gvar1])
db.session.add_all([func, gvar0, gvar1, call])
db.session.commit()
print len(list(call.arg_list))
```

Now I want to store the callsite `func(a, a, a, a, b)` where `func` is some function, `a` and `b` is the global variables. Hence, I want `call.arg_list` to contain 4 duplicated `gvar0` (for `a`), because `a` occurs 4 times. However, the result of `len(list(call.arg_list))` is 2. I guess the reason might be that flask-sqlalchemy removes duplicated `gvar0`. So my question is how to declare the model of `Call` and `GlobalVariable` as well as the table `call_global_variable` so that I can insert multiple duplicated records (say `gvar0`) to the many-to-many relationship `call.arg_list`? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @univerio Each `User` should be filled with 10 `Address`-es. If the `User` has only one address, then the rest 9 `Address` should be filled with the same so that when some `Address.name` is modified, the rest will also be modified. An intuitive method is to duplicate the `Address`. However, flask-sqlalchemy does not permit such duplication.

Comment: For your purpose, You can only save the address once if the use has only one address.

Comment: I do not think that is intuitive. Why do you need the database to contain exactly 10 addresses?

Comment: @univerio Well, the old example is not good enough. I changed the code to be a more practical example where there are 4 `gvar0`-s to be stored. In this example, `gvar0` is referenced for 4 times. Although we can create a wrapper class denoting the reference of some global variable, and store several different references, my question is whether there is some method that can directly store `gvar0` in `call.arg_list`. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Tables are sets, not lists. You need to add a column to `call_global_variable` called `arg_pos` and manage it manually.

Comment: @univerio Thanks for your comment! Maybe you can write an answer and  emphasize that tables are sets, not lists. I have never heard this from any documentation before.